# require.js optimization: deep dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to optimize (i.e. build) my app which is dependent from `ember-data`. So as the path for `ember-data` I set this file https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/main.js but `r.js` includes only this particular file and omit it's dependencies. I thought maybe it's because of some kind of paths issue but I can't see any error messages in console.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your build file (the one you pass to r.js as a build config), you have:

```
findNestedDependencies: true
```

R.js is omitting so called "inline dependencies" by default so if you do have in your main.js i.e.

```
require(["sth"],function(){
   require(["sthelse"]);
});
```

R.js will only load "sth" by assuming that "sthelse" should be loaded during runtime.

; )